# property is not set when ring item is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have following subpage in Prime faces 3.2:

```xhtml
<ui:composition template="index.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="centerContent">

    <h:form id="youtubeform">

        <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Music</h3>
        <p:ring id="basic" value="#{ringView.items}" var="item">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align: center;" layout="block">
                #{item.link}
                <br />
                <p:commandButton update=":youtubeform:itemDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" 
                    title="View" oncomplete="itemDialog.show()" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="oka" target="#{ringView.str2}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:ring>

        <p:dialog header="YoutubeItem Info" widgetVar="itemDialog" 
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true" width="300" >
        <h:outputText id="itemDetail" value="#{ringView.str2}" />  
        </p:dialog>   

    </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

and bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RingView implements Serializable {

    private List<YoutubeItem> items;
    private YoutubeItem selectedYoutubeItem;

    private String str2 = "OK1";

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public void setStr2(String str2) {
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

    public YoutubeItem getSelectedYoutubeItem() {
        return selectedYoutubeItem;
    }

    public void setSelectedYoutubeItem( YoutubeItem selectedYoutubeItem) {
        //this.selectedYoutubeItem = new YoutubeItem( "selected" + i);
        this.str2 = "setSelectedYoutubeItem";
        //this.selectedYoutubeItem = selectedYoutubeItem;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<YoutubeItem>();

        items.add( new YoutubeItem( "link1"));
        items.add( new YoutubeItem( "link2"));
        items.add( new YoutubeItem( "link3"));
        //this.selectedYoutubeItem = new YoutubeItem( "selected");
    }

    public List<YoutubeItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems( List<YoutubeItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

The property string `str2` is not updated when ring item is called.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242732/setpropertyactionlistener-doesnt-update-the-property) a dup?

Comment: no, previous one is deleted

Comment: Is your `h:form` a nested one, I mean, do you have a parent form in your template page? Is your dialog being shown? There could be many issues about this, but at first sight it looks OK. BTW, you don't give a scope to your managed bean.

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes, id="youtubeform" is in <ui::define> so it is included by main template, dialog is shown but proerty set method is never called

Comment: I think you don't understand me, do you have another form in your `index.xhtml` view?

Comment: in index.xhtml I have                 <div id="centerContent">
    <ui:insert name="centerContent" >
     <ui:include src="/pages/maincontent.xhtml" />
     </ui:insert>  AND inside mainContent.xhtml I have <ui:composition>
                <p:panelGrid styleClass="myPanel" style="width:100%" >  (...)
            </p:panelGrid> 
  
     </ui:composition>

Comment: Try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example for your issue, some code I can copy-paste and try. I don't have the `YoutubeItem` class either your template code. It also would be helpful to hear about the JSF implementation version used.

Comment: YoutubeItem has just one variable of type String, also I don't use it at all here, even the String in ringView is not updated, the problem is set setStr2 nor any other Set method is not called on ringView

Comment: If not used at all, you should better replace it just by a String in your example. Try to make it as simple as possible. Minimize your code till you still keep having the issue in the simplest case possible. That way you'll probably be able to see it or, if not, you'll make easier for people here to infer what's going about.

Comment: I have replaced, look, I do <f:setPropertyActionListener value="oka" target="#{ringView.str2}" /> so I just try update String str2 in ringView then show it in dialog, isn't this correct?

Comment: Then update your question with your latest tested code

Comment: this is this version that is posted

Comment: So is `YoutubeItem` class totally unuseful here?

Comment: yes, problem is setStr2 is not called, str2 is not changed, as described

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version are you using ?

Comment: @HatemAlimam This  is version 3.2

Comment: Well I think it's a bug, you might need to upgrade, since too much has been fixed since that version.. got [example](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4927&can=1&q=setPropertyActionListener&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: @HatemAlimam thank you very much, you can post this as an answer

Comment: I'm afraid my comment is not a valid answer, since we've got no 100% issue tracker like your case, but again version 3.2 is so much old.. and posting an answer suggesting an upgrade is a help desk answer :)

Comment: if this is valid then this is correct and only possible thing that might help, I am 100% happy with it and IMO this is perfectly legitimate answer